# RecyclerView with button onItemClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm developping an app with a RecyclerView to show different "posts", each item has a like button which works perfectly fine but I'm now having a hard time because I want to show the details of a post in a seperate activity if the user clicks on it.

How can I start a new activity if the user clicks on anything **except** the like button ?

Comment: see my answer @Archipel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
      recycleview.addOnItemTouchListener(
                        new RecyclerItemClickListener(Activity, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {


                         startActivity(new Intent(Activity,otherclass.class));
                      }
                  })      
              );
```

ADD this Class,

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {

            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've already implemented but if I click on my like button in the adapter won't that load the new activity too ?

Comment: i have same thing in my project then i have put on touch listner to the like button in my case plus button.then on item click listner you can use Intent for new activity.and its perfectly works.You should try it